# How to format a number with regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string, expression

I'm having a problem involving formatting a number. Here in Brazil we got a type of document called "CPF", which is a type of personal ID every citizen have.

So here is an example of a correctly formatted CPF number: 096.156.487-09

I'm trying to use a regular expression to format a string containing a CPF number, but I'm having a hard time at it. My current code is returning the unformatted numbers.

**For instance:** It should output `123.456.789-0` but instead I'm getting `1234567890`.

This is my current code:

```
    String cpf ="09551130401";
    cpf = cpf.replaceAll("(\\d{2})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4})(\\d{2})", "$1.$2.$3-$4");
    System.out.println(cpf);
```

Comment: Seems your regular expression is not matching your input. Your regex wants 14 digits, but gets only 10.

Comment: Have you tried to count the amount of digits in `09551130401` to see if it matches your regex? Do that and you'll be surprised.

Comment: This is exactly the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679323/formating-cpf-with-regex-java asked with another account.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get your right .. But maybe you're looking for this pattern:

```
"(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})"
```

And replace with `$1.$2.$3-$4`.

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nY5gN4/10)

---

**Full Code:**

```
String cpf ="09551130401";
cpf = cpf.replaceAll("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})", "$1.$2.$3-$4");
System.out.println(cpf);
//=> 095.511.304-01
```